Николай Чабановский снова сотрудник? Или так обозначается бывший персонал?
Прошлой осенью создателя ruSO уволили из компании — Николай Чабановский попал под сокращение. А сегодня я, случайно увидев его аватар и ник, заметил, что рядом с ними имеются плашки Сотрудник и Модератор:

Вот ответ на мете, про который я говорю. Самое что интересное, что если посмотреть в комментарии под ним, то рядом с никнеймом этих двух плашек уже нет. В профиле — тоже. Ещё пару деталей: на основном сайте ничего подобного не видно, см. любой ответ, например этот. А на посте, который был написан после увольнения — тоже пусто.
Что происходит? Если это обозначение бывшего персонала — то оно сделано очень коряво. Может, просто баг. Или всё-таки Николай вернулся?
UPD: если это плашка о том, что это бывший сотрудник, то почему её нет на основном сайте (даже на старых сообщениях!)

Технически я пока не вижу никаких признаков того, что Ник вернулся к нам. Также не поступало информации от него самого. Плашек с вашего скриншота также не вижу нигде. У вас точно не стоит никаких расширений браузера, которые могли бы эти плашки добавлять?

Если навести на плашку - появится сообщение...........с другой стороны конечно это не логично делать плашку с сообщением......зачем-то.... Хотя бы писали "экс-сотрудник", тогда было бы яснее

@aepot https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/401244/339911

@αλεχολυτ вижу, спасибо

@αλεχολυτ спасибо за ссылку.

Подозреваю, что сделали привязку к времени публикации.

@Qwertiy не ко времени публикации, а ко времени активности поста. Например, если запостил не будучи модом, потом отредактировал модом, а потом перестал быть модом
